# Cluster for rendering

Tags: cluster

How can I build a cluster for rendering without scripting? It should be a very easy solution and there should be only free tools and of course i would like to use ubuntu.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All cluster calculations are done with a help of a library like OpenMPI. You can not just take an arbitrary application and run it on several PCs at once. 
OpenMPI has excellent Python bindings, you can write all you need on Python + NumPy + SciPy.